# How to test Angular components that use Redux?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, redux, angular5

I have started working on an Angular (5) SPA that uses Redux and I also want to see if I can perform component (unit) testing.

I will provide a simple functionality - fetch some todos data from the server:

#### todo.service.ts

```
  getTodos(): Observable<any> {
    this.ngRedux.dispatch({ type: SHOW_LOADER, message: "Loading TODOs ..." });

    let obs = this.http.get<Array<any>>("api/SampleData/GetTodoList");
      obs.subscribe(result => {
        console.log("Got todos:", result);
        this.ngRedux.dispatch({ type: HIDE_LOADER });
        this.ngRedux.dispatch({ type: FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS, todos: result });
      },
      error => {
        this.ngRedux.dispatch({ type: HIDE_LOADER, message: "" });
        console.error(error);
      });
    return obs;
  }
```

Normally, it is not required to return the Observable object, since this function takes care to dispatch the message on its own subscription. However, in order to test the component, it must get this reference.

#### todo-list.component.ts

```
  constructor(
    private ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>,
    private todoService: TodoService) {
  }

  resetTodoList() {
    this.todoService.getTodos();
  }
```

So, in order to test `TodoListComponent.resetTodoList`, I have to mock `TodoListComponent` dependencies or at least make sure that they are not called when performing the test:

#### todo-list.component.spec.ts

```
describe('TodosComponent', () => {
  let component: TodoListComponent;
  let service: TodoService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    service = new TodoService(null, null);

    component = new TodoListComponent(null, service);
  });

  it('should set todos property with server items', () => {
    spyOn(service, "getTodos").and.callFake(() => {
      return Observable.of([1, 2, 3]);
    });

  // act and assert should come here
  });
});
```

Since `resetTodoList` is not returning anything, I thought of making it return the `Observable` and subscribe to it in my test:

```
  resetTodoList() {
    return this.todoService.getTodos();
  }

  // act and assert part from the test
  component.resetTodoList().subscribe(v => {
      expect(v.length).toBe(3);
  });
```

This pattern seems quite simple, but that means that the developer must take care to return an Observable reference in order to make the function testable.

I am wondering if there are is any alternative to this approach.

**Question:** How to test Angular components that use Redux?

P.S. I will add `package.json` relevant content here to provide a better context:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-redux/store": "^7.1.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "ng-block-ui": "^1.0.4",
    "ng2-select": "^2.0.0",
    "ng2-table": "^1.3.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "tassign": "^1.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `return this.todoService.getTodos()`? I see no problem with testability though since you can mock/spy on this.todoService any way.

Comment: @estus - yes, I have simplified the function. I have also noticed that the service method itself is somewhat more convoluted since it must return the Observable (normally, it does not need to).